# C# Asp.Net HTTP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know what are the fastest way to get results from HTTP request. I work with `httpwebrequest` but I found information about `httpclient`, is it better?

I have few requests at the same time also I want to know if I write the project, for example, in Rust and make the HTTP request from the result, the request is processed on the client side? And the results will be faster? Where does the `httpclient` from c# run? From the server or from the client?

Comment: Please clarify "where the httpclient from c# run? from the server or from the client?".

Comment: You can measure the speed yourself by logging the start and end time of the request. Something like [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) will help.